# Why is the Python 3 REPL not showing method and attribute suggestions on tab when I run "flask shell"?

Tags: python, flask

When I run the python3 (v3.7.3) REPL alone, I am able to see method and attribute suggestions when I press tab. Running "flask shell" (Flask v1.0.2-3) to get inside my app context, I have no such suggestions. Instead, hitting tab actually tabs over like it would in a word processor. I have verified that the same version of Python3 is running in both contexts.

Running all of this on a Debian 10 Vagrant box which I'm using through the urxvt terminal emulator, FYI.

Here's what I get when hitting tab in the Python3 REPL:[Python3 REPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVDxT.png)

Here's what I get when hitting tab in the "flask shell" Python3 REPL:[flask shell Python3 REPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJrWx.png)

Comment: you are comparing an IDE with a terminal, you can't have sugestion on a basic terminal unless you use some library; if you create your flask project with some IDE for example pycharm you will have sugestions

Comment: @Carlo1585 I may have phrased it poorly, but the standard python3 prompt in Debian 10 does provide suggestions of methods and attributes if you press tab after an object. See the images I added above.

Comment: @Carlo1585: They're getting suggestions in an ordinary Python session, not an IDE.

Comment: What happens if you run `import readline; import rlcompleter; readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")` in the Flask shell?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That did prevent me from tabbing over, but no suggestions appear

Comment: Looks like you'd need to do some additional config, and there's some weird interaction with `site` and `virtualenv`: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2604. What's your `virtualenv` version?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That worked! I imagine I'm running something below 16.1, but pip list doesn't even mention virtualenv. Probably will get a modern version with Debian 11.